# Simplest non-constant holomorphic function having a holomorphic square root

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

In the following question

[Example 1.7 Girondo's Introduction to compact riemann surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489426/example-1-7-girondos-introduction-to-compact-riemann-surfaces)

I were asking for a parametrization of hyperelliptic curves. At a certain point, in the answer, I read the following affirmation:

"The simplest holomorphic function $\gamma$ on $D_\epsilon(0)$ with $\gamma(0)=0$ that isn't constant and has a holomorphic square root is $\gamma(z)=z^2$"

So, my question is: why $f(z)=z^2$ is the simplest non-constant holomorphic functions with the above properties and $f(z)=z$ is not?

Comment: Because $f(z)=z$ does not have a holomorphic square root..

Comment: Because there isn't any holomorphic function defined on an open set containing $0$ such that $f^2=id$, of course.

Comment: Can you prove that $z^2$ has a holomorphic square root in $D_\epsilon(0)$, please?

Comment: Isn't it clear that $z$ is a square root of $z^2?$